# ComboBox DropDownList searching for text

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` the `DataSource` property is set to a List of this `Type`:

```
public class ListInfo
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The `DropDownStyle` is set to `DropDownList`, I set the `AutoCompleteSource` to `ListItems` and the `AutoCompleteMode` to `SuggestAppend`.

After some testing the client has come back and asked to be able to find any part of the text value, not just from the start of the text. Most examples that I have seen do this when the `DropDownStyle` is set to `DropDown`,  I can't do that because the user cannot edit the contents of the list just select a value.

I have tried to create a `CustomSource`, but when I try to set the `AutoCompleteMode` to any value I get the following message:

> Only the value AutoCompleteMode.None can be used when DropDownStyle is
>   ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList and AutoCompleteSource is not
>   AutoCompleteSource.ListItems.

I have found this [AutoSuggestCombo](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/631196/ComboBox-with-Suggest-Ability-based-on-Substring-S?fid=1838434&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed&fr=1#xx0xx), but again I hit the problem with the `DropDownStyle`.

How can I either:

1. Use the `ComboBox` with the `DropDownStyle` set to `DropDown`, that doesn't allow end user to enter new elements?
2. Be able to search any part of the `String` value of the `Items`, not just the `StartsWith` that is currently used in the `DropDownList` style?

Is this the opportunity to get started with Rx, or is that route a bloated solution and the learning curve that comes with it? (used simple tutorials so far)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set all Autocompletion properties to none and handle the stuff yourself.
There could be simpler solutions, but you can code the KeyPress event like this.

```
private void comboBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    SortedDictionary<int, ListInfo> dict = new SortedDictionary<int, ListInfo>();

    int found = -1;
    int current = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;

    // collect all items that match:
    for (int i = 0; i < comboBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        if (((ListInfo)comboBox1.Items[i]).Name.ToLower().IndexOf(e.KeyChar.ToString().ToLower()) >= 0)
        // case sensitive version:
        // if (((ListInfo)comboBox1.Items[i]).Name.IndexOf(e.KeyChar.ToString()) >= 0)
                dict.Add(i, (ListInfo)comboBox1.Items[i]);

    // find the one after the current position:
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, ListInfo> kv in dict)
             if (kv.Key > current) { found = kv.Key; break; }

    // or take the first one:
    if (dict.Keys.Count > 0 && found < 0) found = dict.Keys.First();

    if (found >= 0) comboBox1.SelectedIndex = found;

    e.Handled = true;

}
```

You can decide if you want case sensitivity; probably not..