# Using AutoComplete on DropList style ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, autocomplete

I have seen a lot os questions already about implementing a `ComboBox` with `AutoComplete` functionality. I have also seen a few [tutorials](http://www.codescratcher.com/wpf/autocomplete-combobox-wpf/) showing how a DLL can be used.

Here is my XAML for my `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboSongOpen" 
            ItemsSource="{StaticResource SongTitles}"
            SelectedValuePath="Number"
            SelectedValue="{Binding Meeting.OpenSong}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SongListComboBoxItem}" />
```

Looks like:

[image: Songs presented in the combo]

The problem I have is that my `ComboBox` is a `DropList`. There is no need to allow the user to type text into the combo as we must select one of the values in the list. That said, some kind of `AutoComplete` would be great. Specifically, typing the song number and it filter the list down etc.

But I can't see how it can be acheived with a droplist style combo.

### Update

I have tried to follow the link provided in the comments but it is not going right:

```
private void comboSongOpen_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if((e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.D9) ||
        (e.Key >= Key.NumPad0 && e.Key <= Key.NumPad9))
    {
        ComboBox comboBox1 = sender as ComboBox;

        SortedDictionary<int, SongTitleItem> dict = new SortedDictionary<int, SongTitleItem>();

        int found = -1;
        int current = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;

        string number = "";
        if (e.Key == Key.D0)
            number = "0";
        else if (e.Key == Key.D1)
            number = "1";
        else if (e.Key == Key.D2)
            number = "2";
        else if (e.Key == Key.D3)
            number = "3";
        else if (e.Key == Key.D4)
            number = "4";
        else if (e.Key == Key.D5)
            number = "5";
        else if (e.Key == Key.D6)
            number = "6";
        else if (e.Key == Key.D7)
            number = "7";
        else if (e.Key == Key.D8)
            number = "8";
        else if (e.Key == Key.D9)
            number = "9";

        // collect all items that match:
        for (int i = 0; i < comboBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {

            if (((SongTitleItem)comboBox1.Items[i]).Number.ToString().IndexOf(number) >= 0)
                dict.Add(i, (SongTitleItem)comboBox1.Items[i]);
        }
        // find the one after the current position:
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, SongTitleItem> kv in dict)
            if (kv.Key > current) { found = kv.Key; break; }

        // or take the first one:
        if (dict.Keys.Count > 0 && found < 0) found = dict.Keys.First();

        if (found >= 0) comboBox1.SelectedIndex = found;

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

My If statement is not being triggered. Also, it is a pitty I have to keep converting the song numbers to text. But why is my if statement failing?

I added the switch latter to atleast get the right string value to compare against but this still seems flawed.

If I am on 015 (for example) and type 113 it will not end up at 113. And there seems to be no way to "roll back" on what you have typed.

Comment: I think you'll have to do that yourself

Comment: @HaitamZanid What would be the basic approach to doing this myself? Can you direct me to the appropriate articles please?

Comment: You can do it (unseen) in the KeyPress/Down event, see this articile : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024105/combobox-dropdownlist-searching-for-text

Comment: @HaitamZanid Does it matter that that question is for `WinForm` as opposed to `WPF`?

Comment: I believe you have those events in WPF too, am i wrong?

Comment: @HaitamZanid Updated question. Hit an issue with the sample provided.